# Where to include a captcha?

Tags: php, security

I'm developing a web application, for the first time, and have a question about where to have a captcha displayed.

On my site, I have Recaptcha on the public (ie. not logged-in) 'Contact' page, where anyone can submit questions or feedback. But after the user is successfully logged in, with a session started, is it necessary to have a Recaptcha on the same page? As the site sits now, I don't have a Recaptacha displayed if the user is logged in.

I've seen some sites where even if you're logged in, you have to type in the captcha to submit a comment, but that seems sort of strange to me.

Thanks for your help!

Reg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a captcha in places where you are concerned about spam.

Even after having a user log in, spam may still be a valid concern. After all, I could easily create an account and then have a script run while being logged in as that user.

However, your major concern will likely not be with targeted attacks, but rather with bots who scour the internet for easy forms to spam, which are surprisingly common. To defeat that attack, a captcha would not be necessary for logged in users, since those bots will never be anything but a guest.

As such, you'll have to balance user convenience with blocking against the threat of a targeted attack. I'd recommend not bothering with the captcha for logged-in users until you become large enough to have that concern, but it's your call, entirely dependent on your particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you will remove captcha for authenticated user at all - then it will be possible to pass the captcha (manually) and do whatever you want (spam, be annoying, etc).

The common idea nowadays is to show captcha each N'th request of some specific action, like posting a comment.

Or like stackoverflow does: it is a possible amount of comments within some interval, after which you'll get a captcha.

Comment: And I like something about Gmail: if you have encountered password error for once or more, you need captcha. For the first time, no need. I think it's the best way to use captcha in login forms.

Comment: Agreed, sites that make registered users repeatedly pass captcha tests make no sense to me. You could also remove captchas once users have passed a certain point (e.g. reputation on SO) that indicates they're trustworthy.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: even with 11k+ rep I sometimes need to fill the captcha ;-)

Comment: yes, it's a feature that SO doesn't implement. I used SO as an example of a site where trustworthiness had a definitive metric.